# $|G|=p^kq$, $p,q$ prime, $p^k\leq 2q$ implies one of the Sylow subgroups is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I could use some help with this one:

Let $G$ be a group, $|G|=p^kq$ where $p,q$ are prime and $p^k\leq 2q$.

Prove that at least one of the Sylow subgroups is normal.

Comment: If a Sylow $q$-subgroup is not normal then the condition $p^k \le 2q$ implies that there are $p^k$ Sylow $q$-subgroup, so there are $p^k(q-1)$ eleemnts of order $q$, and the remaining .$p^k$ elements must form a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm not that good at number theory... I understand your argument and I see why the number of Sylow $q$-subgroups is $q+1$ and why it *divides* $p^k$, yet not why it's equal...

Comment: If it is $p^l < p^k$ then $p^l = q+1$ contradicts $p^k \le 2q$. You don't need to be an expert in number theory to see that!

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks, sometimes I seem to miss the obvious :/